# Laravel backpack widget adds view twice

Tags: laravel-backpack

I have a crud controller for a model. Inside the setupCreateOperation function, I add fields, but before them I call the widget to load the view

```
protected function setupCreateOperation(): void
    {
            Widget::add([
                'type' => 'view',
                'view' => 'dt::template_fields_script',
            ]);
            /* Adding fields */
    }
```

view code:

```
@push('after_scripts')
    <script> console.log("hello world")</script>
@endpush
```

However, the view is inserted twice and, accordingly, both times the console log is processed.
What could be the problem? If you remove Widget::add, then the view is not added at all

I also tried to add a block in this way. The widget still adds the block twice

```
Widget::add()->type('script')->content('assets/js/admin/document/template_script.js');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the widget is globally added to all the pages of the crud. The script that was added is called at least on viewing, at least on creation, at least on update. However, due to the fact that I also separately add a widget::add() inside the setupCreateOperation(), it is called a second time and therefore it is duplicated on the creation crud page. I got around this by refusing to use the widget and using the view field type

```
$this->crud->addColumns([
       [
         'name'  => 'template_script',
         'type'  => 'view',
         'view' => 'dt::template_fields_script',
       ],
```

View

```
@push('after_scripts')
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            console.log()
        });
    </script>
@endpush
```